# User password hashed and salted, trying to allow the user to change the password on front end?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

At first password change was working but when i added hash and salt now passwords can not be changed by user
(keep getting: Current password is not correct)

```
if (count($_POST)>0) {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from users WHERE username='"
.$_SESSION["user"] . "'");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

    if($_POST["currentPassword"] == $row["password"]) {
mysql_query("UPDATE users set password='" . $_POST["newPassword"] . "'  
WHERE username='" . $_SESSION["user"] . "'");
$message = "Password Changed";

}   else $message = "Current Password is not correct";
}
```

Here is the register page:

```
session_start();
    if($_SESSION['user']!=''){header("Location:welcome.php");}
$dbh=new PDO('mysql:dbname=doctor;localhost', 'root', '');
$email=$_POST['mail'];
$password=$_POST['pass'];

    if(isset($_POST) && $email!='' && $password!=''){
$sql=$dbh->prepare("SELECT id,password,psalt FROM users WHERE 
username=?");
$sql->execute(array($email));
      while($r=$sql->fetch()){
$p=$r['password'];
$p_salt=$r['psalt'];
$id=$r['id'];
}
$site_salt="mysalt";/
$salted_hash = hash('sha256',$password.$site_salt.$p_salt);

    if($p==$salted_hash){
    $_SESSION['user']=$id;
    header("Location:welcome.php");
       }else{
 echo "Username OR Password is Incorrect...";
}
}
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
function validatePassword() {
var currentPassword,newPassword,confirmPassword,output = true;

currentPassword = document.frmChange.currentPassword;
newPassword = document.frmChange.newPassword;
confirmPassword = document.frmChange.confirmPassword;

if(!currentPassword.value) {
currentPassword.focus();
document.getElementById("currentPassword").innerHTML = "required";
output = false;
}
else if(!newPassword.value) {
newPassword.focus();
document.getElementById("newPassword").innerHTML = "required";
output = false;
}
else if(!confirmPassword.value) {
confirmPassword.focus();
document.getElementById("confirmPassword").innerHTML = "required";
output = false;
}
if(newPassword.value != confirmPassword.value) {
newPassword.value="";
confirmPassword.value="";
newPassword.focus();
document.getElementById("confirmPassword").innerHTML = "not same";
output = false;
}   
return output;
}
```

Comment: `if($_POST["currentPassword"] == $row["password"]) {` is comparing the passwords as plaintext.... if your hashing the password in the database, then of course they won't match

Comment: You have to hash the input password before comparing it with the stored password hash.  That's kind of the whole point of a hash, it's *different* from the password.

Comment: Time for you to start learning about [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)/[password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: Also a good time to start learning about MySQLi or PDO and using Prepared statements with bind variables.... you're using them on the register page, so use them for the password change too.... be consistent

Comment: ^ everything they said, just for emphasis :)

Comment: And a bit of inteligent code indentation would make your code easier for all of us to read and much easier for you to debug

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there *is* a user with that username, there's a problem with your first script:

```
if($_POST["currentPassword"] == $row["password"])
```

This compares the *raw password* from the form (`$_POST["currentPassword"]`) with a *hashed password* from the result (`$_POST["currentPassword"]`). What you need to do is *compare the hash forms of both passwords*. You need to *hash the one from the form* with the same hash function you used before storing the user's password.